# Obtener dataframe previo filtrado una columna con diferentes parámetros - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Es posible obtener (Casi seguro que si) mediante funciones de `Pandas` un dataframe en el cual filtremos una columna por una serie de valores que se encuentren en una lista?

Es decir, para obtener un dataframe a partir de un valor de una columna empleamos,

```
df = df.loc[df['Nombre'] == 'Ana']
```

Así obtendría un dataframe que donde solo aparezcan esas filas donde la columna nombre contenga Ana.

Pero yo lo que quiero es pasar más de un nombre que están en una lista,

```
nombres_analisis = ['Claudia','Lucia','Ana']
df = df.loc[df['Nombre'] == nombres_analisis]
```

Se hacer esto mediante un bucle `for` pero no lo consigo solo con `Pandas`.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada columna de un dataframe es un objeto de tipo `Series`, y este objeto tiene un método llamado [`Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) que hace justo lo que buscas:

```
nombres_analisis = ['Claudia','Lucia','Ana']
df = df[df.Nombre.isin(nombres_analisis)]
```

Observa que he quitado el `.loc`, pues lo que devuelve `Series.isin()` es otra serie de booleanos indicando con `True` si el elemento estaba en la lista y con `False` si no. Esa serie de booleanos se usa dentro de `[ ]` para quedarse sólo con las filas de `df` que tengan un `True` en la correspondiente Series.

(Nota adicional. Si el nombre de columna no contiene espacios o signos de puntuación, como el caso de `Nombre`, puedes usar `df.Nombre` en vez de `df["Nombre"]`)